# Erro ao excluir segundo item de List

Tags: c#

Estou usando o seguinte código pra excluir itens:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
{
    var remover = listaPedido.SingleOrDefault(r => r.ItemOffline == int.Parse(gridPedido.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString()));
    if (remover != null)
    {
        listaPedido.Remove(remover);
        gridPedido.DataSource = listaPedido;
    }   
}
```

Na primeira vez que excluo um item, funciona corretamente. Na segunda vez dá erro de OutOfIndex (mesmo eu tendo itens na minha lista):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vejam pela tela por trás do erro, que ainda tenho 3 registros no dataGrid.

O que pode ser?

Comment: Se tem 3, você acessa do 0 ao 2, no código está 3.

Comment: no código está a coluna que estou usando pra fazer a comparação. ele vê qual a linha tem a coluna itemOffline == coluna[3] do grid

Comment: @bigown, também, o erro que dá é no índice 2. então teria que funcionar com a quantidade de itens que eu tenho no momento

Comment: fiz outro teste aqui e o erro sempre dá no índice da quantidade de itens que tenho na tabela (no caso da imagem aparece 2 porque tenho três itens, como você citou acima)

Comment: Já tentou fazer desta forma: `gridPedido.CurrentRow.Value.ToString()`?

Comment: em que parte do código @AckLay? se for referente à busca pelo registro para excluir, o sistema faz corretamente, incluí dois messageBox e verifiquei que tanto ele encontra o r.itemOffline corretamente quanto encontra a linha correta também. imagino que tenha que dar algum tipo de update no grid :/

Comment: Pois tente então desta forma: gridPedido.Update();
    gridPedido.Refresh();

Comment: mesmo erro :/ tentei com os dois códigos que você sugeriu @AckLay. Tem uma outra sugestao pra excluir itens de uma lista?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não postou o código inteiro, somente o trecho da deleção, mas irei supor o seguinte (baseado no erro que ocorre):

- O teu grid é inicializado com a variável `listaPedido`, que por sua vez deve ser um `List<QualquerCoisa>`;
- Em algum momento você inicializa a lista com o `gridPedido.DataSource = listaPedido`;
- Note que quando você exclui um item da `listaPedido`, você reassocia esse `listaPedido` ao teu `gridPedido.DataSource`, que na prática não tem efeito nenhum. O teu grid já possui o `listaPedido` como seu `DataSource`;
- O tipo `List<T>` não possui eventos de notificação de mudança embutidos - na prática, seu grid não é avisado da mudança e confia na renderização do estado anterior (quando ele ainda tinha 3 itens), gerando o erro.

### Solução

Simplesmente encapsule sua fonte de dados em um `BindingList<QualquerCoisa>` *(substitua `QualquerCoisa` pelo nome real da sua classe)*. Assim:

```
BindingList<QualquerCoisa> _bsListaPedido;  // Variável Global da Classe

void CarregaGrid() 
{
    _bsListaPedido = new BindingList<QualquerCoisa>(listaPedido);
    gridPedido.DataSource = _bsListaPedido;
}
```

Ao remover o item da lista, remova do *BindingList*:

```
_bsListaPedido.Remove(remover);
```

Isso irá notificar o Grid da mudança de forma adequada e deverá ocorrer tudo bem.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver assim:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
{
    var remover = listaPedido.SingleOrDefault(r => r.ItemOffline == int.Parse(gridPedido.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString()));
    if (remover != null)
    {
        listaPedido.Remove(remover);
        gridPedido.DataSource = null;
        gridPedido.DataSource = listaPedido;
    }   
}
```

acrescentando a linha `gridPedido.DataSource = null;` fez com que o `dataGridView` "zerasse" e atualizei o mesmo novamente com a lista atual.